# How to load new icons in xcode for IOS 7?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have having quite a bit of trouble updating my app to IOS 7. Everything is ready, but I have several warning icons around the Icon section. 'No image with correct dimensions found'.

It says I need to provide a 120x120 icons and a few others. I have the icons ready to go, but when I try and select them in xcode, it cannot even find them? I have tried putting them in the same folders as all the other icons with no luck.

I have checked the paths and everything seems fine, and following the naming conventions.

I see several answers that say to use the 'Asset Catalog' but would prefer not to do this if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the icons to your project (drag onto the left panel).

Then, the part you may not want: look for Images.xcassets (if it's a new project, it comes in your main project folder).
Drag the image from your project (you can't drag directly from finder for some reason) to the correct icon description.

Is there any reason you don't want to use the Asset Catalogue? It will take care of everything else automatically for you. Just follow the 'size' attribute for each empty icon box and you're done.

On non-required images, just drag one to the left box of the asset catalogue and this will create an entry for all sizes of that image.

For more information on assets/images, watch the Paul Hegarty lectures (Stanford). The newest series CS193p 2013-2014 "Developing iOS7 Apps" has a great introduction to the new features if you watch the "xCode 5" lecture.